# How to chain delete pairs from a vector in C++?

Tags: c++, vector, std-pair, chain

I have this text file where I am reading each line into a `std::vector<std::pair>`,

```
handgun bullets
bullets ore
bombs ore
turret bullets
```

The first item depends on the second item. And I am writing a delete function where, when the user inputs an item name, it deletes the pair containing the item as second item. Since there is a dependency relationship, the item depending on the deleted item should also be deleted since it is no longer usable. For example, if I delete `ore`, `bullets` and `bombs` can no longer be usable because `ore` is unavailable. Consequently, `handgun` and `turret` should also be removed since those pairs are dependent on `bullets` which is dependent on `ore` i.e. indirect dependency on `ore`. This chain should continue until all dependent pairs are deleted.

I tried to do this for the current example and came with the following pseudo code,

```
for vector_iterator_1 = vector.begin to vector.end
{
    if user_input == vector_iterator_1->second
    {
        for vector_iterator_2 = vector.begin to vector.end
        {
            if vector_iterator_1->first == vector_iterator_2->second
            {
                delete pair_of_vector_iterator_2
            }
        }

        delete pair_of_vector_iterator_1
    }
}
```

Not a very good algorithm, but it explains what I intend to do. In the example, if I delete `ore`, then `bullets` and `bombs` gets deleted too. Subsequently, pairs depending on `ore` and `bullets` will also be deleted (`bombs` have no dependency). Since, there is only one single length chain (`ore-->bullets`), there is only one nested `for` loop to check for it. However, there may be zero or large number of dependencies in a single chain resulting in many or no nested `for` loops. So, this is not a very practical solution. How would I do this with a chain of dependencies of variable length? Please tell me. Thank you for your patience.

**P. S. : If you didn't understand my question, please let me know.**

Comment: what happens when you delete "bullets"? Does "bullets ore" remain in the vector?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One (naive) solution:

- Create a queue of items-to-delete
- Add in your first item (user-entered)
- While(!empty(items-to-delete)) loop through your vector
- Every time you find your current item as the second-item in your list, add the first-item to your queue and then delete that pair

Easy optimizations:

- Ensure you never add an item to the queue twice (hash table/etc)

Comment: Wow, Beth! That is actually a very optimal solution! And I think it will work perfectly! I have written the code, but I haven't tested it yet. I'm pretty sure it doesn't have any errors, though! Thank you very much! Kudos to you! :-)

Comment: I'm so glad to hear it @WDRKKS :)

Answer (score 1):

personally, I would just use the standard library for removal:

```
vector.erase(remove_if(vector.begin(), vector.end(), [](pair<string,string> pair){ return pair.second == "ore"; }));
```

remove_if() give you an iterator to the elements matching the criteria, so you could have a function that takes in a `.second` value to erase, and erases matching pairs while saving the `.first` values in those being erased.  From there, you could loop until nothing is removed.

For your solution, it might be simpler to use `find_if` inside a loop, but either way, the standard library has some useful things you could use here.

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't help myself to not write a solution using standard algorithms and data structures from the C++ standard library. I'm using a `std::set` to remember which objects we delete (I prefer it since it has log-access and does not contain duplicates). The algorithm is basically the same as the one proposed by @Beth Crane.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <utility>
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>
#include <set>

int main()
{
    std::vector<std::pair<std::string, std::string>> v
    {   {"handgun", "bullets"},
        {"bullets", "ore"},
        {"bombs", "ore"},
        {"turret", "bullets"}};

    std::cout << "Initially: " << std::endl << std::endl;
    for (auto && elem : v)
        std::cout << elem.first << " " << elem.second << std::endl;

    // let's remove "ore", this is our "queue"
    std::set<std::string> to_remove{"bullets"}; // unique elements

    while (!to_remove.empty()) // loop as long we still have elements to remove
    {
        // "pop" an element, then remove it via erase-remove idiom
        //  and a bit of lambdas
        std::string obj = *to_remove.begin();
        v.erase(
            std::remove_if(v.begin(), v.end(),
                           [&to_remove](const std::pair<const std::string,
                                        const std::string>& elem)->bool
            {
                // is it on the first position?
                if (to_remove.find(elem.first) != to_remove.end())
                {
                    return true;
                }
                // is it in the queue?
                if (to_remove.find(elem.second) != to_remove.end())
                {
                    // add the first element in the queue
                    to_remove.insert(elem.first);
                    return true;
                }
                return false;
            }
                          ),
            v.end()
        );
        to_remove.erase(obj); // delete it from the queue once we're done with it
    }

    std::cout << std::endl << "Finally: " << std::endl << std::endl;
    for (auto && elem : v)
        std::cout << elem.first << " " << elem.second << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for taking time to type that out, vsoftco. I posted a detailed reply for you as an answer. Please check it out. Thanks.

Comment: @WDRKKS I have updated my code, so it erases also elements having the first position equal to the item. See also my comment about iterators below your code.

Answer (score 0):

**@vsoftco** I looked at Beth's answer and went off to try the solution. I did not see your code until I came back. On closer examination of your code, I see that we have done pretty much the same thing. Here's what I did,

```
std::string Node;

std::cout << "Enter Node to delete: ";

std::cin >> Node;

std::queue<std::string> Deleted_Nodes;

Deleted_Nodes.push(Node);

while(!Deleted_Nodes.empty())
{
    std::vector<std::pair<std::string, std::string>>::iterator Current_Iterator = Pair_Vector.begin(), Temporary_Iterator;

    while(Current_Iterator != Pair_Vector.end())
    {
        Temporary_Iterator = Current_Iterator;

        Temporary_Iterator++;

        if(Deleted_Nodes.front() == Current_Iterator->second)
        {
            Deleted_Nodes.push(Current_Iterator->first);

            Pair_Vector.erase(Current_Iterator);
        }

        else if(Deleted_Nodes.front() == Current_Iterator->first)
        {
            Pair_Vector.erase(Current_Iterator);
        }

        Current_Iterator = Temporary_Iterator;
    }

    Deleted_Nodes.pop();
}
```

To answer your question in the comment of my question, that's what the `else if` statement is for. It's supposed to be a directed graph so it removes only next level elements in the chain. Higher level elements are not touched.

`1 --> 2 --> 3 --> 4 --> 5`

Remove 5: `1 --> 2 --> 3 --> 4`

Remove 3: `1 --> 2     4     5`

Remove 1: `2     3     4     5`

Although my code is similar to yours, I am no expert in C++ (yet). Tell me if I made any mistakes or overlooked anything. Thanks. :-)

Comment: Seems right, you should try learning some of the algorithms in the standard library + lambda functions. Mine doesn't take care of your `else if` case, but can easily be adaptable. Best thing is to test it extensively, and make sure it's right. The only issue I see is what happens if you push 2 elements of the same type into the queue? Will it be OK? Also, use `++iterator` whenever possible, as it avoids creating a useless temporary. Also, if you think Beth solution is OK, don't forget to eventually vote/accept it.

Comment: One more comment: are you sure you're not invalidating the iterators? AFAIK, `vector::erase` invalidates iterators and references at or after the point of the erase, so even if you copy it, you effectively copy a pointer to zone of memory that won't be valid anymore. For small vectors, things may look fine, since the memory is not erased/reallocated, but you shouldn't bet on it. You should use the iterator returned by `erase` to point to the next valid iterator, see e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/q/1604588/3093378. That's why it's preferable to use `std::remove_if`.

Comment: @vsoftco Thanks for the heads up about the `vector::erase` and the `std::remove_if`. I say this because I have another program that makes horrible use of `std::list` to erase elements using temporary iterators. Also, I don't think pushing same type of element will occur, and even if it does, I don't think it will cause much of a problem. It will get deleted in the first occurrence and get ignored in the second occurrence. But the extra iteration time will be wasted though. I'll have to do something about it.Anyway, thanks for your help. Upvoting your answer and accepting Beth's. :-)

Comment: To be on the safe side, I'd recommend saving the iterator returned by `erase` as your iterator-to-next. If the vector performs a re-allocation, then with the code you have now you end up with dangling iterators.