# Is this (auto && elem : v) syntax simple C++? what compiler should I use to have it compile?

Tags: c++, compilation, iterator, set

I used to code in C++ 12 years ago, but left it for other simpler languages due to my job.

I'd like to renew my knowledge and tried to compile the solution proposed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29422628/6019417), just to try this new way to iterate on vectors. But ran into a compile error:

> `expected initializer before ‘:’ token`

I didn't know it was possible to avoid explicit declaration of iterators like that in `C++` with the use  of this `(auto && elem : v)`. What version of `C++` is it?

### b.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <utility>
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>
#include <set>

int main()
{
  std::vector<std::pair<std::string, std::string>> v
  {   {"handgun", "bullets"},
      {"turret", "bullets"}};

  std::cout << "Initially: " << std::endl << std::endl;
  for (auto && elem : v)
    std::cout << elem.first << " " << elem.second << std::endl;

  return 0;
}
```

### Compilation

```
$ cc b.cpp  -std=c++0x  -o myprog
```

### Errors

> b.cpp: In function ‘int main()’: 
>   b.cpp:15: error: expected initializer before ‘:’ token 
>   ...

C++ Compilers I use: `g++`

```
$ g++ --version
```

gives

```
g++ (GCC) 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-3)
Copyright (C) 2010 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
```

Comment: Probably your compiler doesn't support ranged for loops.

Comment: what compiler are you using?

Comment: `cc` ? Isn't that a C compiler ?

Comment: Thanks. What kind of compiler should I use then?

Comment: OK thanks guys! I was following this http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/howto-compile-and-run-c-cplusplus-code-in-linux/ and believed I was using C++ compiler.

Comment: @J.Chomel To use GCC as c++ compiler call `g++`, similar for Clang call `c++`.

Comment: @Barry, sorry but I am using a C++ compiler. `g++` has same version as `cc` and `gcc` on my system.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following pupper's advice, I adapted my code to the below:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    std::vector<std::pair<std::string, std::string>> v
    {   {"handgun", "bullets"},
        {"turret", "bullets"}};

    std::cout << "started: " <<  std::endl;
    std::vector<std::pair<std::string, std::string>>::iterator Current_Iterator = v.begin();
    while(Current_Iterator != v.end())
    {
        std::cout << Current_Iterator->first << " " << Current_Iterator->second << std::endl;
        Current_Iterator++;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

It still doesn't compile with the `gcc` on my system, giving

> ``` b.cpp:(.text+0x134): undefined reference to ``std::cout' ```
>   ...

But it works with `g++`:

```
$ g++ b.cpp   -std=c++0x  -o myprog && ./myprog
started:
handgun bullets
turret bullets
```

Comment: I edited out the "meta" bit about your experience. Whilst I appreciate your frustration, it doesn't belong in the answer. Back yourself, you're doing fine. C++ can be dense given a host of target environments, keep at it.

Answer (score 9):

Your compiler is too old. ***Ranged-based*** `for` loops weren't added until [4.6](https://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-4.6/changes.html).

Also, ignore the comments. `cc` is usually symlinked to `gcc`. From the manual:

> GCC recognizes files with these names and compiles them as C++
>   programs even if you call the compiler the same way as for compiling C
>   programs (usually with the name `gcc`).

Comment: The comments are not accurate, but OP still needs use g++ (or add other options). The reason for that is the next paragraph in the manual: `However, the use of gcc does not add the C++ library`

Comment: @user2079303 A) The real issue is OP's compiler is too old. B) Ranged-based for loops are a language construct, they don't need `libstdc++` to work.