# Deleting Elements of Vector Inside a Loop

Tags: c++, vector

I have a vector, `words`, of type: `vector<string>`. I am trying to delete every element of `words` that is not contained in the `vector<string>` called `largest_family`, but can't seem to accomplish this. Any help is appreciated.

```
vector<string>::iterator it = words.begin();
for (int i = 0; i < words.size(); i++)
{
    if (find(largest_family.begin(), largest_family.end(), words[i]) == largest_family.end())
    {
        words.erase(it);
    }
    else
    {
        it++;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The right way to perform such task is:

```
for (vector<string>::const_iterator it = words.begin(); it != words.end();)
{
    if (find(largest_family.begin(), largest_family.end(), *it) == largest_family.end())
    {
        it = words.erase(it);
    }
    else
    {
        ++it;
    }
}
```

There are many related topics on SO: for example [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/347441/erasing-elements-from-a-vector) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1604588/iterate-vector-remove-certain-items-as-i-go).

Comment: You should call `cbegin()` and `cend()` if you're going to use `const_iterator`.

Comment: @GillBates it depends on the standard. I don't see *c++11* tag here, that's why I didn't use them.

Comment: @EdgarRokyan C++ is C++14 now, and C++ means that. I see no C++03 tag.